# Print all set operations between two pandas indices

Tags: pandas, set, indices

Is there a more idiomatic/economical way of printing the results of all set operations between two overlapping data frame indices?

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd._testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.index = range(3, 8)

intersec = list(df1.index.intersection(df2.index))
diff12 = list(df1.index.difference(df2.index))
diff21 = list(df2.index.difference(df1.index))

print(f"{intersec = }") # intersec = [3, 4]
print(f"{diff12 = }") # diff12 = [0, 1, 2]
print(f"{diff21 = }") # diff21 = [5, 6, 7]
```

I have more than 2 frames and getting all combinations this way is too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
_ = [
    print(f"{k} = {v.index.to_list()}")
    for k, v in {
        "intersec": df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)],
        "diff12": df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)],
        "diff21": df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)],
    }.items()
]
```

Output:

```py
intersec = [3, 4]
diff12 = [0, 1, 2]
diff21 = [5, 6, 7]
```